# How to find If array contains two or more objects

Tags: ios, nsarray

I'm attempting to implement the containsObject but with two or more parameters, is this possible?

Currently I've got:

and apparently there's too many arguments. I've delved through Apple's docs but I'm yet to find anything. Any suggestions?

```
if ([ myArray containsObject:@"1", @"2"]){
    NSLog(@"if");
} else if([ myArray containsObject:@"1", @"2",@"3",@"4"]) {
   NSLog(@"else if");
}else if([ myArray containsObject:@"1", @"2",@"3"]) {
   NSLog(@"else");
}
```

### myArray:-

```
myArray is (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can check subsets of array**

```
 NSArray *arry1= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
        NSArray *arry2= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

        NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:arry1];
        NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:arry2];

        if ([set2 isSubsetOfSet:set1])
        {
            NSLog(@"array1 contains all elements of array 2");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"array1 does not contains all elements of array 2");
        }
```

Comment: i have provided complete source and its working fine . Post your code how you are using it.

Comment: ur first answer working i had mistack while checking

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([myArray containsObject:@"1"] || [ myArray containsObject: @"2"]) {
    NSLog(@"if");
} else {
   NSLog(@"else");
}
```

Comment: This is for the case you want to check 2 or 3 objects. If you want to check a lot of objects, use @Gandalf code

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own custom code. Pass all the required objects in method as an array and iterate over the array of all objects. If any object is not found, `return false`.

```
-(BOOL)containsObjects:(NSArray*)arrObj
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    for(CustomObject *cObj in arrObj) {
        result = [mainArray containsObject:cObj];
        if(result == NO) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: what is this CustomObject?

Comment: @Krish It's a class name. This is a generic solution where you can compare objects of any kind. In your case if your array contains string objects, you can use `NSString` at it's place or `id` type.

Comment: this is not suitable because in my case some times my array havin9 (1,2,3,4) and some times may having(2,3) values